# The Javascript window navigator browser name doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, properties

It is said that we can use javascript `navigator` function to get all the browser related properties of a machine. I had tried to get the same [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/rvcnb3bc/) as,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Name is " + navigator.appName +
        "<br>Code name is " + navigator.appCodeName;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

to get the browser name. But when I open it in chrome, the `navigator.appName` gives as Mozilla. So how can I get the app name as chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I please use below codes to check your browser name

```
    function myFunction() { 
    if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
        alert('Opera');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {
        alert('Chrome');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        alert('Safari');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {
        alert('Firefox');
    } else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) {
        alert('IE'); 
    } else {
        alert('unknown');
    }
}
```

I think that may help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get it from `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: It returns `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/rvcnb3bc/1/ How can my code come to know exactly as chrome if opened in chrome?